# Get the following day after a month

Tags: php

Just a noob question,

For example I have date 2013-08-01 // 1 August 2013
How do I get same day next month. ex. 2013-09-01 // 1 Sept 2013

Thanks

Comment: And what should happen on Jan, 31?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With using `strtotime`

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('next month',strtotime('2013-08-01')));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. this is the exact answer to my question.

Comment: Really what you're looking for? https://eval.in/40805

Comment: This is about February. Is this a problem @Jason? I can modify it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a PHP dev, but it seems to me you want [`DateTime::add`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

```
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
```

As noted in the documentation though, you need to be careful near the end of a month - adding 1 month to January 31st 2001 ends up with March 3rd, for example. (Not the behaviour I'd choose, but that's a different matter.) If you're always dealing with the 1st of the month, you should be okay.

Comment: Please not in OOP way

Comment: $sDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sDate.' + 1 month '));

Comment: @Jason The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) gives examples both ways.

Comment: Apart from having hundreds of answers showing how to add n hours/day/months/whatever to a date, this will *not* give the same day on the next month due to months not being fixed size.

Comment: @Gordon: It will on the example given, surely - there's *always* a 1st of the month. I would expect this only to give problems for days near the end of the month. (I'll add a note for that.)

Comment: Reason for the behavior is outlined in http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#SEC120

Comment: @Gordon: Still seems broken to me :) It makes more sense (IMO) to return the end of the month.

Comment: Well, we had tons of "bug reports" about this behavior over the years so in retrospect you might be right on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date_add function (procedural) or Datetime::add (OO). Here is an example of each:

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month'));
```

or

```
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 month'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dateTest = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$dateTest + 1 month"));
```